# detect swipe gesture horizontally and vertically in andengine

Tags: android, andengine, swipe, gesture, swipe-gesture

I am using AndEngine and trying to detect the swipe gesture in my game. There is a class(SurfaceGestureDetector.java) in andengine.But i dont know how to use it. When i try to instantiate in onCreateScene() method it throws exception.Is there any method or internal class is provided for it or any other method to detect the swipe in andengine.Here is my code.

```
public class AETopDownBackground extends SimpleBaseGameActivity implements IOnSceneTouchListener{

        private int CAMERA_WIDTH=800;
        private int CAMERA_HEIGHT=480;
        private Camera mCamera;
        private Scene mScene;
        private BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas atlas,txchrAtlas;
        private TextureRegion trHill;
        //private Sprite mSpriteHill;
        private AnimatedSprite mSpriteMan;
        private TiledTextureRegion trTiledMan;

        @Override
        public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mCamera=new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
            return new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), mCamera); 

        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreateResources() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/"); 
            atlas= new BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas(getTextureManager(), 800, 1300);
            trHill=BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(atlas, this, "road_bg.png"); 


            try {
                atlas.build(new BlackPawnTextureAtlasBuilder<IBitmapTextureAtlasSource, BitmapTextureAtlas>(0, 0, 0));
            } catch (TextureAtlasBuilderException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            atlas.load();


            txchrAtlas= new BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas(getTextureManager(), 256, 92,TextureOptions.BILINEAR);
            trTiledMan= BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createTiledFromAsset(txchrAtlas, this, "player_forword.png",4, 1);

            try {
                txchrAtlas.build(new BlackPawnTextureAtlasBuilder<IBitmapTextureAtlasSource, BitmapTextureAtlas>(0, 0, 0));
            } catch (TextureAtlasBuilderException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            txchrAtlas.load();

        }

        @Override
        protected Scene onCreateScene() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());
            mScene = new Scene();       
            mScene.setBackground(new Background(Color.CYAN));

            mScene.setOnSceneTouchListener(this); 
            //gdetectorl= new MySurfaceSwipeDetector(getApplicationContext());

            //final float textureHeight = trHill.getHeight();
            /* Create the hill which will appear to be the furthest
            * into the distance. This Sprite will be placed higher than the
            * rest in order to retain visibility of it */
            Sprite hillFurthest = new Sprite(0, 0, trHill,
            mEngine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());


            //ParallaxBackground background = new ParallaxBackground(0.3f, 0.3f,0.9f) {
            AutoParallaxBackground background = new AutoParallaxBackground(0.3f,0.3f, 0.9f, 50){
                /* We'll use these values to calculate the parallax value of the
                background */
                float cameraPreviousY = 0;
                float parallaYValueOffset = 0;
                /* onUpdates to the background, we need to calculate new
                * parallax values in order to apply movement to the background
                * objects (the hills in this case) */
                @Override
                public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
                /* Obtain the camera's current center X value */
                final float cameraCurrentY = mCamera.getCenterY();
                /* If the camera's position has changed since last
                * update... */
                if (cameraPreviousY != cameraCurrentY) {//cameraPreviousX != cameraCurrentX
                /* Calculate the new parallax value offset by
                * subtracting the previous update's camera x coordinate
                * from the current update's camera x coordinate */
                parallaYValueOffset += cameraCurrentY - cameraPreviousY;
                    //parallaxValueOffset=parallaxValueOffset+10;
                /* Apply the parallax value offset to the background, which
                * will in-turn offset the positions of entities attached
                * to the background */ 
                this.setParallaxValue(parallaYValueOffset);
                System.out.println("Camera parallaxValueOffset:"+parallaYValueOffset); 

                //this.setParallaxValue(0);
                /* Update the previous camera X since we're finished with
                this
                * update */
                cameraPreviousY = cameraCurrentY;
                }
            //  this.setParallaxValue(2);
                super.onUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);
                }
            };
                    //negative value in this method indicates movement.To change the direction of movement use (+)positive  value
                    background.attachParallaxEntity(new ParallaxEntity(10,hillFurthest));



                    /* Set & Enabled the background */
                    mScene.setBackground(background);
                    mScene.setBackgroundEnabled(true);


                    mSpriteMan = new AnimatedSprite(310, 250, trTiledMan, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
                    mSpriteMan.setScale(3); 
                    mSpriteMan.animate(100);
                    mScene.attachChild(mSpriteMan);         



            return mScene;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene, TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionUp()){
                //Toast.makeText(this, "touched", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mSpriteMan.setPosition(pSceneTouchEvent.getX(), pSceneTouchEvent.getY()); 
            }


            return true;
        }

    }                   @Override
                    protected boolean onSwipeLeft() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        onSurfaceGesture("test"); 
                        return true;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected boolean onSwipeDown() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        onSurfaceGesture("test"); 
                        return true;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected boolean onSingleTap() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        onSurfaceGesture("test"); 
                        return true;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected boolean onDoubleTap() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        onSurfaceGesture("test"); 
                        return true;
                    }
                };                  
                    this.mSGDA.setEnabled(true);



        return mScene;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene, TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionUp()){
            //Toast.makeText(this, "touched", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //mSpriteMan.setPosition(pSceneTouchEvent.getX(), pSceneTouchEvent.getY()); 


        }


        return true;
    }


    private void onSurfaceGesture(final String str){ 

        try {
            Looper.prepare();
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("Action is :"+str); 
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I tried the following link but dont know how to use this in my activity.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17105657/swipe-scenes-in-andengine

Answer (score 0):

Your code is badly formatted half-way but to use SurfaceGestureDetector you need to subclass it and implement the detection methods. Then you pass the onSceneTouchEvent to the detector like this:

```java
private MySubclassedSurfaceGestureDectetor gestureDetector;

@Override
public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene, TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {
    return gestureDetector.onManagedTouchEvent(pSceneTouchEvent);
}
```

It will magicly (not that magicly if you look at the source :P) detect the gestures for you.